# Conversion of monthly and quarterly data into annual in R

Tags: r, data-conversion

Hi I am trying to learn to use FRED Data to convert monthly and quarterly into annual data. My data looks like this:

```
   Date FEDFUNDS
7/1/2000    6.54
8/1/2000    6.5
9/1/2000    6.52
10/1/2000   6.51
11/1/2000   6.51
12/1/2000   6.4
```

Previously, seeing other posts I tried using the following to convert monthly to quarterly.

```
library(tidyverse)
data<- read_csv(file.choose())
head(data)
data$Date=as.Date(data$Date, formate="$m/$d/%y")
data<-arrange(data,Date)
library(zoo)
data$qdate<-as.yearqtr(data$Date)
library(date)
data_qrtly<-data %>%
  group_by(qdate) %>%
  summarise_all(mean)
```

But I'm having difficult in trying the "DF" in converting monthly or quarterly to yearly data. Any help will be very appreciated.

Comment: If `x` is a `yearqtr` or `yearmon` object then as.integer(x) is the year since both are stored as the year + fraction of a year for the month or quarter.

Answer (score 0):

How do you want to summarize the data? I assume you want the `mean` of FEDFUNDS by year. This is straightforward to do in the `tidyverse`:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

test_data <- tribble(~Date, ~FEDFUNDS,
                     "7/1/2000", 6.54,
                     "8/1/2000", 6.5,
                     "9/1/2000", 6.52,
                     "10/1/2000", 6.51,
                     "11/1/2000", 6.51,
                     "12/1/2000", 6.4)

#convert the date into a date type column
#create a new "year" column
test_data %>% 
  mutate(Date = lubridate::mdy(Date),
         year = lubridate::year(Date)) %>% 
  group_by(year) %>% 
  summarize(fedfunds_mean = mean(FEDFUNDS))

# A tibble: 1 x 2
year fedfunds_mean
<dbl>         <dbl>
2000          6.50
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, I think it was super helpful. I had two follow-up questions

1) I'm new in R, so sorry for the silly question in advance, but how do I use the tribble for my entire dataset rather than specifying the individual observations? it's a time series observation for the 30 years, I understood what you did with the lubridate, but a quick suggestion with how to use for the entire data set would be extremely helpful.

2) Is there anyway I could convert the entire new year column into a dataset (like the write.csv command?)

Comment: @ShaneMurphy 1) i only used tribble to create a toy dataset. You will need to read the FRED dataset into R with something like readr::read_csv or read_tsv, depending on the delimeter. I don't know what your data source looks like. https://github.com/business-science/tidyquant and http://sboysel.github.io/fredr/ are two packages you could use to retrieve the data from the FRED API.

2) I don't know what you mean by "convert into a dataset". write.csv saves the dataframe (not an individual column) to disk.